# Combine Inner Concat Observables

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

I'm new to RxJS and having a mental block.  My solution works, but I know it's a hack.  What's the proper way to do the following?

```
// Desired Console Log: {x: 'abcd', y: 'efgh'}

const x = Rx.Observable.of('abcd').delay(1000);
const y = Rx.Observable.of('efgh').delay(1000);

Rx.Observable.concat(x,y)
.scan((acc, cur) => {
  if (cur.includes('a')) {
    acc.x = cur;
  }
   if (cur.includes('e')) {
    acc.y = cur;
  }
  return acc
}, {x: false, y: false})
.filter(x => x.y === 'efgh')
.subscribe(x => console.log(x))

// {x: 'abcd', y:'efgh'}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Rx.Observable.concat(x,y)
  .zipIterable(['x','y'], (v1, v2) => {
    let result = {};
    result[v2] = v1;
    return result;
  })
  .toArray()
  .map(objects => Object.assign({}, ...objects))
  .subscribe(console.log.bind(console, '>> '));
```

Provided that the order is kept, i.e. the first element is x and the second y

Comment: Thank you!  .toArray() is what I needed.  I'm curious why you used .zip?  This also gives the correct output without zip.  .toArray()
  .map(array => ({x: array[0], y: array[1]}))

Comment: Well, zip will be cleaner if you have many keys and not just x, y. If it's always x, y, I'd choose your implementation

Comment: It's only X and Y... for now.  Thank you for the explanation and your help!